# Why Str(CDbl(Now())) returns 43185.44166666667?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Today is 26/03/2018.
Why `Str(CDbl(Now()))` returns `43185.44166666667`?
and
`Str(CLng(Now()))` returns `43185`? I am expecting a string starting with 26032018...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Date is a the number days since 31 December 1899, and the time component is the decimal fraction of a day.

That's why you're getting a numeric value.

If you want to format the `Date` as a `ddmmyyyy` string, you should use the `Format$` function

```
Debug.Print Format$(Now(),"ddmmyyyy")
```

Comment: 30-12-1899 not 31-12-1899. `Format(CDate(0), "yyyy-mm-dd")` returns 1899-12-30.

Comment: You're right, the specification says 30 December 1899, so that makes 31-Dec-1899 become "Day 1". It's also worth noting the difference in Excel, where 28-Feb-1900 is 59, and 1-Mar-1900 is 61, but in VBA 28-Feb-1900 is 60 and 1-Mar-1900 is 61. See a great blog post about the dates, by Spolsky, at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Answer (score 1):

Dates in Access and VBA are defined as doubles where the whole numbers are days, and the fractions are fractions of a day, starting from 30-12-1899.

If you want to cast a date to a formatted string, use `Format`:

`Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy")` will return your expected result.

Comment: `Format` will cast to a `Variant (String)`. To cast to a `String`, use `Format$`.